# Can't install matplotlib on Mac (Python)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am French, I am a student in chemistry and I don't know much about Python. I need to install matplotlib on my Mac for my program to work fine, but I tried and it didn't work... Can you help me ?
Thank you very much

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MdLq.png)

Comment: Have you installed matplotlib? Use `pip` to install it... Wait, you say "I tried and it didn't work", what do you see that let you know "it didn't work"?

Comment: Or, simply a question, what's the error you met during **installing** matplotlib?

Comment: I've watched a video on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dszbjTd2lw8  but the 2nd step didn't work

Comment: I downvoted because the sentence "it didn't work" **still** not having any necessary information.

Comment: You're probably trying to run the command inside the python shell. Can you try opening another terminal, and running the command again ?

Comment: I am sorry I told you I don't know much about Python so I can't explain more... Unless you watched the video

Comment: I just want to install it on my computer, I did my program on the computers in my university so matplotlib is installed in them, but when I try it on my computer it appears the message like in the picture in the description of my problem

Comment: @VivescereDiscere I tried both, it says that "install" is invalid syntax

Comment: Try [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/#macos). It will install many scientific packages including matplotlib for you.

Comment: @ayhan I will try this thank you !! Hope it'll work

Comment: @ayhan I've dowloaded it but it keeps showing me the same message... :(

Comment: You might need to restart your computer for changes to take effect. Another alternative is to search for conda prompt in your computer and run python there.

Answer (score 0):

Run `pip install matplotlib` to install the module.

Comment: No Syntax error : it doesn't recognize "install" ....

Comment: Exit the Python shell first (`control`+`Z`).

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal 
execute:  pip install matplotlib

It didn't work?

Comment: No Syntax error : it doesn't recognize "install" ....